# Weird MVC Sitemap error once ever few days on the live production boxes only. Multiple nodes with the same URL '/Home.mvc.aspx/Index' were found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitemap

So I have an MVC web app, it's currently on MVC 3, C#.

I used MVC Sitemap and every once in a while we get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple nodes with the same URL '/Home.mvc.aspx/Index' were found. XmlSiteMapProvider requires that sitemap nodes have unique URLs.
Generated: Fri, 18 May 2012 14:46:20 GMT

System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'StudentPortal3G.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapException: An error occured while parsing the SiteMap XML. Check the inner exception for more details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple nodes with the same URL '/Home.mvc.aspx/Index' were found. XmlSiteMapProvider requires that sitemap nodes have unique URLs.
   at System.Web.StaticSiteMapProvider.AddNode(SiteMapNode node, SiteMapNode parentNode)
   at MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapProvider.AddNode(SiteMapNode node, SiteMapNode parentNode) in D:\Project Files\JCDCHelper\WebApp\MvcSiteMap.Core\MvcSiteMapProvider.cs:line 356
   at MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapProvider.AddNode(SiteMapNode node) in D:\Project Files\JCDCHelper\WebApp\MvcSiteMap.Core\MvcSiteMapProvider.cs:line 336
   at MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapProvider.BuildSiteMap() in D:\Project Files\JCDCHelper\WebApp\MvcSiteMap.Core\MvcSiteMapProvider.cs:line 264
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapProvider.BuildSiteMap() in D:\Project Files\JCDCHelper\WebApp\MvcSiteMap.Core\MvcSiteMapProvider.cs:line 309
   at MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapProvider.GetRootNodeCore() in D:\Project Files\JCDCHelper\WebApp\MvcSiteMap.Core\MvcSiteMapProvider.cs:line 365
   at System.Web.SiteMapProvider.get_RootNode()
   at MvcSiteMap.Core.MvcSiteMapProvider.get_RootNode() in D:\Project Files\JCDCHelper\WebApp\MvcSiteMap.Core\MvcSiteMapProvider.cs:line 120
   at System.Web.SiteMap.get_RootNode()
   at StudentPortal3G.Controllers.BaseController.LoadHeaderInfo() in d:\CC\StudentPortal3G\Source\StudentPortal3G\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 40
   at JCDCHelper.MVCController.JCDCBaseController..ctor(INetLog passNetLog, IUserMaintBLL passUserMaintBLL) in d:\CC\JCDCHelper.MVCController\Source\JCDCHelper.MVCController\JCDCBaseController.cs:line 47
   at JCDCHelper.MVCController.JCDCBaseController..ctor() in d:\CC\JCDCHelper.MVCController\Source\JCDCHelper.MVCController\JCDCBaseController.cs:line 33
   at StudentPortal3G.Controllers.HomeController..ctor() in d:\CC\StudentPortal3G\Source\StudentPortal3G\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 35
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

But I *know* that there are not two of these nodes, and if it were that the error would happen every time.

Did anyone experience this before?

Comment: I use MvcSiteMapProvider on a project and I don't like it.  One of the issues I have with it is that it's not thread-safe (or at least that's my conclusion).  I get similar errors if I'm doing my first load on multiple pages at the same time.  I don't know any way around it other than contributing to the source.  My guess is that /home is the first node in your xml and it's already loaded when it starts running again.

Comment: I'm a rep whore, so I'll post this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MvcSiteMapProvider on a project and I don't like it. One of the issues I have with it is that it's not thread-safe (or at least that's my conclusion). I get similar errors if I'm doing my first load on multiple pages at the same time. I don't know any way around it other than contributing to the source. My guess is that /home is the first node in your xml and it's already loaded when it starts running again.

Comment: It's going to be abit before I can add threadsafeness to the xml reading in our local copy, when I get a chance to do it, if it fixes the issue I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No worries.  I'll come back if I find something on my end.